# Hint for the study of function

Tags: analysis, functions

I must study this function:
$$ 
\tan\left(\exp\left(\frac{4x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)
$$

but I don't know how determine the domain! I saw on Wolfram alpha that there are four asymptotes!
How can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the function $g(x)=4x/(1+x^2)$ is bounded and has a maximum and a minimum. So you know what are the values taken by $\exp(g(x))$. Do they contain points where $\tan$ is undefined?

---

(*Added after accept.*)

Let's do some checks. The maximum of $g$ is attained at $x=1$, and $g(1)=2$. The minimum is, of course, attained at $x=-1$ and $g(-1)=-2$, because the function is odd.

Therefore the values taken by $\exp(g(x))$ are those in the interval $[e^{-2},e^2]$. The function $\tan$ is undefined, in that interval, at $\pi/2$, $3\pi/2$, because $5\pi/2>e^2$. Let $k$ be one of these value: we have to find for what values of $x$ we have $\exp(g(x))=k$ or $g(x)=\log k$. This is a quadratic:
$$
x^2\log k-4x+\log k=0
$$
whose (reduced) discriminant is $4-(\log k)^2$. We have solutions when $\log k\le 4$. Now

- $\log(\pi/2)\approx0.45$
- $\log(3\pi/2)\approx1.55$

so there are (two) solutions for each of these possibilities, which gives four candidates to get vertical asymptotes (and they indeed are).

The derivative of $f(x)=\tan(\exp(g(x))$ is easy:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\exp(g(x)))}\exp(g(x))g'(x)
$$
which has the same behavior as $g'(x)$. So the function is

- decreasing for $x<-1$,
- increasing for $-1<x<1$,
- decreasing for $x>1$,

excluding, of course, the points where the function is not defined.

Finally,
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\tan 1=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).
$$

Comment: @malloc $g(x)=\log(\pi/2)$, which reduces to a quadratic. For convenience, set $k=\log(\pi/2)$ in the calculations.

Comment: thanks, I understand, but how I can get the other results?

Comment: resolved, I just had to think a little bit more .. in the end it was not very difficult!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You need to solve, for x, g[x]=log[(2n+1) Pi / 2].

This simply reduces to a quadratic equation in "x" for a given "n".

You will easily show that there are two real solutions for n=1 (x = 0.114 and x = 8.743) and two real solutions for n=2 (x= 0.474 and x = 2.105). For n > 2, there is no real solution and this is also easy to prove).

So, you have your four asymptotes.

Comment: this is what I was looking for.. can you explain me with more details... I don't have understand why you take g(x)=log(..), I can get the solution of of x=0,1.. and 8,7... putting g(x)=pi/2, but for the other 2 result?

Comment: @malloc. Sorry, there was typo's. Tan(y) is undefined for Pi/2, 3 Pi / 2, 5 Pi / 2, ... and any odd number multiplied by Pi / 2. Is this clearer ? Please answer.

Comment: don't worry, I understand how you get the other result, but I can't figure out why you put g[x]=log[(2n+1) Pi / 2]?

Comment: Your function is Tan[Exp[g[x]]]. The argument which makes the tangent undefined is then Exp[g[x]]=(2n+1) Pi/2. Then, take logarithms of both sides. Is it better that way ?

Comment: With $(2n+1)$ you intend$(n^2+1)$?It's just a typo?

Comment: @malloc. (2 n + 1).

Comment: ahhhhhhh sorry, I made you waste a lot of time ..$(2n+1)It's the period right?

Comment: @malloc.ahhhhhhhhh ! you got it !